# Anyone able to translate this SAS code to R? Cluster bootstrap for calculating accuracy statistics for correlated eye data

Tags: statistics

I am trying to use the methods mentioned here https://iovs.arvojournals.org/article.aspx?articleid=2770806 to perform a cluster bootstrap for correlated eye data.
Can anyone help me translate the SAS code in  appendix 3 to R?

Attempted translation but got stuck with the random number generator.